# Determine if the following function is continuous on $ (0,0) $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Determine if the following function is continuous on $ (0,0) $
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
 (1+x^2y^2)^{-1/(x^2+y^2)},& \text{ if } (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 
 1,& \text{ if } (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

Conjecturing that $ \lim _ {(x, y) \to (0,0)} f (x, y) = 1 $.

My attempt is,
$$\begin{align*}
0 &\leq | f (x) -L|\\
 &=|(1+x^2y^2)^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}-1|\\ &\leq |(1+x^2y^2)^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}|+1\end{align*}$$

Hence I do not know what else to do because in another limit like this but with the euler function, you can limit that using that the function is strictly increasing, but here you cannot do that because $ (1 + x ^ 2y ^ 2) $ is not strictly increasing , so I don't know how to limit that exponent with the function $ (1 + x ^ 2y ^ 2) $.

Comment: Does it help that $ab\le (a+b)^2/4$? (AM-GM)

Answer (score 2):

$0 \leq \frac 1 {x^{2}+y^{2}} \ln (1+x^{2}y^{2}) \leq \frac 1 {x^{2}+y^{2}} x^{2}y^{2}\leq \frac 1  2|x||y| \to 0$. So $ \frac 1 {x^{2}+y^{2}} \ln (1+x^{2}y^{2}) \to 0$. Multiply by $-1$ and  take exponential.

Comment: How do you get $\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}\le\frac12|x||y|$?

Comment: That simply says $(|x|-|y|)^{2} \geq 0$. It is also  special  case of AM-GM inequality. @Karl

Comment: But the sign $ - $ in the exponent, what do you do with it? On the right side of the inequality, I have to arrive at $ 0 $, and with this inequality that you propose, I do not arrive at $ 0 $.

Comment: @JamesA.Agamez If  a function $g(x,y)$ tends to $0$ so does $-g(x,y)$.

Comment: I already understood your idea, thank you very much for the help provided :).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use Bernoulli's inequality to obtain the desired result. We have:
$\left(1+x^2y^2\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}\ge 1+\dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac{x^2+y^2+x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}\implies \left(1+x^2y^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}\le\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2+x^2y^2}= h(x,y)$. Also: $x^2+y^2 \ge x^2 \implies \dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2} \le \dfrac{1}{x^2}\implies -\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2} \ge -\dfrac{1}{x^2}\implies \left(1+x^2y^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}\ge \left(1+x^2y^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} = \left(\left(1+x^2y^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{x^2y^2}}\right)^{y^2}=g(x,y)$. So: $g(x,y) \le f(x,y) \le h(x,y)$. But both $h,g \to 1$ when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ because $0 \le \dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} \le x^2$, and thus $\dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} \to 0$. Thus $f(x,y) \to 1 = f(0,0)$, proving continuity of $f$ at $(0,0)$. Note that $g(x,y) \to e^{-0} = 1$ when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help too :).

Comment: @JamesA.Agamez: No problem. Did you understand my solution? if there is a part of it that you are still not sure about, let me know...

Comment: Don't worry. Of course I understood her, her answer is very well understandable and explained.